# Use text field to add a record in Yii2

Tags: php, text, yii2, field

How can I add a record via a text  field in yii2?

Please explain what I have to do in the Controller and View and models and anything that I need

```
public function actionAdd() {
  ????
}
```

Comment: this is basic tutorial for an input form 
 .. hope is useful  https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-contact-form-in-yii2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must have form with the action name like this

controller :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  $model = new News();
  if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
     if($model->save())
         return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id ]);
     }
}
```

in view folder:

create.php:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'text') ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('submit') ?>

 <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Comment: the result is this : Calling unknown method: app\models\EntryForm::save()

Comment: this is example you must have table like news and create model by gii for it and then use this , I offer to you first learn oop and next lean MVC and after that come to yii you must read document yii